# Writing enumitem's to a file

Tags: enumitem

I am a teacher and often need to make worksheets and reviews that have answer keys.  With the help of TeX StackExchange, I have a fairly robust system at this point with the notable exception that it does not work with `enumitem`.  The error message that I am getting is beyond my LaTeX wisdom.  Is there anyone who can help me out?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newwrite\answerkeyfile

\AtBeginDocument{%
   \immediate\openout\answerkeyfile=\jobname.keys
}

\begingroup
\catcode`\#=12
\gdef\hashchar{#}%
\endgroup

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\answerkey}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\#\hashchar
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\@currentlabel.\ }
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{ }
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\closeout\answerkeyfile
}

\begin{document}

Answer these questions:

%% With \begin{enumerate}, this code works.  Switch to 
%% \begin{enumerate}[label=\emph{\alph*)}] and it fails.
%\begin{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\emph{\alph*)}]
   \item Question 1 \answerkey{Answer 1}
   \item Question 2 \answerkey{$\frac{1}{2}$}
   \item Question 3 \answerkey{\begin{tikzpicture}
                          \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
                          \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{enumerate}

Answer Key:

% Copy the mwe.keys to mwe.ans, then use this to show the answers.
%\input{mwe.ans}

\end{document}
```

As noted in the comments, switch the enumerate line to the one that uses `enumitem` features and this will fail.  What can I do to not compromise the
system I have and yet still use `enumitem`?

Here is the error that I am getting:

> ! Use of \@item doesn't match its definition. \text@command #1->\def
>   \reserved@a {#1}\ifx \reserved@a \@empty \let \check@... l.37   \item
>   Question 1 \answerkey{Answer 1}

UPDATE:

The comment below that it is not actually the enumitem code but rather the \emph (or similarly \textbf, \textit, etc) in the label that is the issue was interesting.  The solution below that creates a "fake" label is the least invasive/complicated, while adding the functionality that label formatting makes it through to the answer key document.  The code I started with did not put the answers into a true enumerate environment, so the solution proposed below which does this is overkill for my situation.  In the end, based on the help/guidance below, I rewrote the \answerkey command as follows:

```
\newcommand{\answerkey}[2][.]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\#\hashchar
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\expandafter\unexpanded
         \expandafter{\@currentlabel}#1\ }
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\unexpanded{#2}}%
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{ }
  \endgroup
}
```

In actual use, it looks like this:

If the default item labels are used:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Question 1 \answerkey{Answer 1}
```

If enumitem label formatting is used:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.}]
    \item Question 1 \answerkey[]{Answer 1}
```

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I suggest to use `\protected@write{\answerkeyfile}{}{\@currentlabel.\ }` rather. `\noexpand` will result in `\@currentlabel` being written to the file which is probably not wanted.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You are correct in noting that my approach does not output the label properly.  I will delete the earlier comment.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Unfortunately my suggestion does only provide compilation but not the desired content in the output file. `\@currentlabel` seems to be deeply unexpandable here

Comment: Is there a way to explain to a non-power-user what it is about enumitem that requires the special handling?  Why is it that I can put a whole tikz picture into my answer file without troubles, yet I can't have the enumerant written there without special processing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to expand `\@currentlabel` and write that content to the file with `\unexpanded`, however, this will place 'fake' item labels and not really `\item` layout in the file.

A better strategy would be to 'replicate' the `enumerate` environment in the output file.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newwrite\answerkeyfile

\AtBeginDocument{%
   \immediate\openout\answerkeyfile=\jobname.keys
}

\begingroup
\catcode`\#=12
\gdef\hashchar{#}%
\endgroup

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\answerkey}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\#\hashchar
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\@currentlabel}.\ }
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{ }
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\closeout\answerkeyfile
}

\begin{document}

Answer these questions:

%% With \begin{enumerate}, this code works.  Switch to 
%% \begin{enumerate}[label=\emph{\alph*)}] and it fails.
%\begin{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\emph{\alph*)}]
   \item Question 1 \answerkey{Answer 1}
   \item Question 2 \answerkey{$\frac{1}{2}$}
   \item Question 3 \answerkey{\begin{tikzpicture}
                          \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
                          \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{enumerate}

Answer Key:

% Copy the mwe.keys to mwe.ans, then use this to show the answers.
\immediate\closeout\answerkeyfile
\input{\jobname.keys}

\end{document}
```

**Another approach by writing `\begin{answerenumerate}` to the file, which is a copy of `enumerate`, basically**:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newwrite\answerkeyfile

\AtBeginDocument{%
   \immediate\openout\answerkeyfile=\jobname.keys
}

\begingroup
\catcode`\#=12
\gdef\hashchar{#}%
\endgroup

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\answerkey}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\#\hashchar
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\string\item}
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{ }
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\closeout\answerkeyfile
}

\begin{document}

Answer these questions:

\newlist{answerenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[answerenumerate]{label=\emph{\alph*)}}


\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\emph{\alph*)},
  before={\immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\string\begin{answerenumerate}}},
    after={\immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\string\end{answerenumerate}}}
}

\begin{enumerate}
   \item Question 1 \answerkey{Answer 1}
   \item Question 2 \answerkey{$\frac{1}{2}$}
   \item Question 3 \answerkey{\begin{tikzpicture}
                          \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
                          \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{enumerate}

Answer Key:

% Copy the mwe.keys to mwe.ans, then use this to show the answers.
\immediate\closeout\answerkeyfile
\input{\jobname.keys}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice.  (+1)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Thanks ;-) I've updated with another (better?) way

Comment: I have been playing around with your "fake" solution.  At first glance, the "Answer" formatting appears to be very similar to the "Question" formatting.  Can you suggest what might reveal the problems with this solution (or when I might encounter difficulties with it)?

Comment: The only way I have been able to reveal it so far is by using the default item labels in which case the "Answer" version does not have a period after the label.

Comment: Actually, I believe I have an answer to my own comment here.  The formatting in the Answer portion does not maintain things like the "itemsep" or "topsep" settings from enumitem.  With respect to the labels, it appears to be the same except for the default label which puts a period after the label.

Comment: @ChristopherDonham: You have to specify the same `itemsep` etc. values to the answerenumerate `\setlist`

Comment: Ok.  I understand.  For my application, it is better to actually not redo the enumerate.  The reason is that occasionally, I will miss an answer in a long review sheet.  If that happens, then all subsequent answers would be numbered incorrectly.  It is better for me to actually pass the enumerant value through to the answer sheet.  Bottom line:  I'm going with your "fake" solution as noted above.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

You should use the `ref` feature of `enumitem`, also exploiting the fact that the package braces the `\@currentlabel`.

Define `\answeritem` as you like.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newwrite\answerkeyfile

\AtBeginDocument{%
   \immediate\openout\answerkeyfile=\jobname.keys
}

\edef\hashchar{\string#}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\answerkey}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\#\hashchar
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\answeritem\@currentlabel}
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\unexpanded{#1}^^J}%
  \endgroup
}
\protected\def\answeritem#1{\item[\emph{#1})]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Answer these questions:

%% With \begin{enumerate}, this code works.  Switch to 
%% \begin{enumerate}[label=\emph{\alph*)}] and it fails.
%\begin{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\emph{\alph*}),ref=\alph*]
   \item Question 1 \answerkey{Answer 1}
   \item Question 2 \answerkey{$\frac{1}{2}$}
   \item Question 3 \answerkey{\begin{tikzpicture}
                          \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
                          \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{enumerate}

Answer Key:

\immediate\closeout\answerkeyfile
\begin{enumerate}
\input{\jobname.keys}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output in `\jobname.keys`:

```
\answeritem {a}
Answer 1

\answeritem {b}
$\frac {1}{2}$

\answeritem {c}
\begin {tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1); \end {tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Some more words about the problem.

The key `ref` defines what's stored in `\@currentlabel` (typically written in the `.aux` file, but you're using it yourself). Writing in the `.aux` file is safe, because `\protected@write` is used by LaTeX; however you're using `\write` and `\emph` is not a command TeX likes to see there. You could use `\protected@iwrite` (you find how to define it on the site), but the trick I suggest above is even better because you can then decide what `\answeritem` gets expanded to. It's important its definition is `\protected`, so it will remain untouched during the `\write` operation.

Comment: Can you help me to understand your solution?  I don't see what the "ref" statement in the enumitem is achieving and can't find a good reference (bad pun) in the enumitem documentation (in other words, I read what it said in the enumitem documentation, and still don't understand the purpose of "ref" in this context).

Comment: @ChristopherDonham The error message you get is misleading; it was due to `\@currentlabel` containing `\emph`, which is not a command that TeX likes to see in the argument to `\write`.

Comment: So how does your "ref" help?  The documentation seems to use "ref" in conjunction with "\ref", but I'm not seeing any \ref in your code (unless I am missing it).

Comment: @ChristopherDonham I added a longer comment to my answer.

Comment: That makes more sense to me.  If I could click on this for another "useful" point I would :-)